# Android Setting Height of Child Views Based on Height of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with several child views.  I can call setLayoutParams() on the child views to set the heights but I'd like the heights to be based on the overall height of the layout, somewhat like weight in LinearLayout but a bit more complex. How do I get the height of the layout in order to set the height on the child views?  The only thing I've come up with is to override onMeasure() on the layout.  onMeasure() gives me the (possible) height of the layout.  In onMeasure() I call setLayoutParams on the children and then call super.onMeasure() letting the superclass use the just adjusted heights in the child layout params.  Is it OK to call setLayoutParams() on children in onMeasure()?  onMeasure() seems to be the only way to know that the possible height of the layout has been calculated and what that possible height is.

Comment: code snippets of what you are trying to achieve will help a lot

Comment: What you are describing sounds like what people do with a custom ViewGroup that sizes and positions all of its children according to its own specifications.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html